# Instantiating Camel components from XML snippet without Spring

Tags: java, apache-camel

How do I instantiate a Camel component from XML snippet without Spring?

Say, I have a snippet, something like this:

```
<dataFormats>
    <json id="jack" library="Jackson" prettyPrint="true"/>
....
</dataFormats>
```

, which I want to be parsed and effectively returned for me as the result of

```
JsonDataFormat jack = new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
jack.setPrettyPrint(true);
```

or even things like this, which I expect to be able to instantiate a Processor from:

```
<setHeader headerName="inputRegistryHandler">
   <simple>${header.CamelFileNameOnly}</simple>
</setHeader>

<mvel>request.headers.foo == 'bar'</mvel>
```

etc.

Hope the XML support isn't going to be ditched in Camel 3?

**The solution**

Following the @Sergei I. advice below I have written something like below

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.apache.camel.model:org.apache.camel.model.language");
Unmarshaller unmarshal = jc.createUnmarshaller();
ProcessorDefinition pd = (ProcessorDefinition) unmarshal.unmarshal(serviceDefinitionElement);
rc = new DefaultRouteContext(_camelContext);
Processor processor = pd.createProcessor(rc);
_camelContext.addService(processor, true);
```

It ate a DOM Element containing

```
<camel:setBody>
    <camel:simple>mike check one two</camel:simple>
</camel:setBody>
```

like a charm, creating a functionable Processor

Probably I will need to add more java packages to be able to parse more types of Camel XML snippets

**Update**
I had to add `_camelContext.addService(processor, true);` to the solution above. This magic thing loads all the Camel Context beans into the processor, which gives us an ability to omit some configuration. For example, this will add the `ObjectMapper` to the Jackson dataformat without us mentioning it specifically, and the `prettyPrint` flag starts being respected:

```
<camel:unmarshal>
    <camel:jacksonxml unmarshalTypeName="java.util.Map"/>
</camel:unmarshal>
<camel:marshal>
    <camel:json library="Jackson" prettyPrint="true"/>
</camel:marshal>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camel uses JAXB to marshal and unmarshal XML. The XML models are defined in `org.apache.camel.model` package. You can try the following:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SetHeaderDefinition.class);

Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
SetHeaderDefinition setHeaderDefinition = (SetHeaderDefinition) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

CamelContext class has function loadRoutesDefinition that allow to load xml file.

Xml file should have structure like this:

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
   <from uri.....
  </route>
</routes>
```